# Which student got better marks in the examination?

Tags: normal-distribution, problem-solving

Jack and Jill study in different section of the same class. On a recent exam, Jack scored 98 out of 100 while Jill scored 97 out of 100. However, we know that in Jack's section the mean score was 80 with a standard deviation of 5, while in Jill's section the mean score was 82 with a standard deviation of 4. The scores in each section are normally distributed.
Relative to each one's section, which student did better on the exam?

Comment: cuold you share your thoughts?

Comment: I could not understand A to Z of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest calculating the $z$ score for each student where 
$$
z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
$\mu $ is the mean and $\sigma $ is the standard deviation.
The student with the largest $z$ has performed, relative to the mean and measured in units of standard deviation, the best.